# Visual Basic 2010 List to txt file?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How do you convert a list into a .txt file using vb.net?
Heres my process:

1. Download file from ftp server.(Multiple lines!)
2. Convert to list.
3. Convert list back to txt.(HOW?)
4. Upload to ftp server.

Edit: Talking about a `Listbox`
      Thats the code I use to convert it into a List.

```
Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\stammiliste\list.txt")
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lines)
```

Comment: what is *your* definition of `List`?

Comment: Iam talking about a Listbox.

Comment: why cant you reverse what you did to put it in the ListBOX?

Comment: I think it would be helpful for people to know why you need to convert your list back to .txt; maybe there is some way to skip some of your steps if you really just need to (say) put newlines in a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such code:

```
Dim items = listBox1.Items.OfType(Of Object).Select(Function(item) item.ToString())
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("D:\file.txt", items)
```

You can also use `listBox1.GetItemText(item)` instead of `item.ToString()`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!